# TCPClient runs into timeout after sending message to TCPListener

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcplistener

I want to create a .NET Core TCP server listening for incoming messages. I created a small class for testing purposes:

```
internal class TCPServer
{
    private readonly TcpListener tcpListener;

    public TCPServer()
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(messageBuffer, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

            Console.WriteLine("Message from tcp client: " + dataReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

When sending messages to that listener the client itself runs into a timeout. As you can see here

[image]

I tried to solve it by adding this line

```
tcpClient.Close();
```

but then I get this error

[image]

How can I send messages to that server without getting an error?

Comment: TCP is robust because every message gets an ACK and when the ACK is not received message is resent automatically up to 3 to 5 times depending on settings.  The timeout indicates the ACK was not received.  You timeout after 30 seconds which probably you retried 5 times every 5 seconds and then after 30 seconds the conneciton closed.

Comment: Looks like the client sent message and then closed before server received message.  The client shouldn't not close.

Comment: so you think the code is fine and the client tool should not close the client?

Comment: I think there may be a race condition if the client immediately closes after sending the data. The server may not of gotten all the data and then ends up with the timeout because the TCP does the retries.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start your test server? Have you checked the port 1234 is opened? I would recommend checking it via "telnet 127.0.0.1 1234"

If YES could you share the client's code?

If NO could you share the code starting your server?
I've tried to run it via the code above and it works pretty well to me with the **telnet** tool as a client

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TCPServer server = new TCPServer();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class TCPServer
{
    private readonly TcpListener tcpListener;

    public TCPServer()
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        tcpListener.Start();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient     tcpClient     = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                byte[]        messageBuffer = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int           bytesRead     = networkStream.Read(messageBuffer, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string        dataReceived  = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Message from tcp client: " + dataReceived);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            tcpListener.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not fix the issue, you just moved the problem in to a `Task`

Comment: I just wanted to highlight that it could be a problem of the way Olaf is starting the server. For example, *await server.Start();* call inside *async static void Main* leads to an issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you dispose of the client socket on your loop. Once you establish a client socket, you need to keep that socket alive.

This isn't proper "server" code, but it will show you what I mean and fix your issue:

```
while (true)
{
    var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

    while(true){
        var messageBuffer = new byte[4096];
        
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data...");
        int bytesRead;
        
        try
        {
            bytesRead = tcpClient.GetStream().Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
        }catch{ break; } // disconnected
        
        var dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Console.WriteLine($"Message from tcp client ({bytesRead} bytes): {dataReceived}");
    }
}
```

This solution will make this work, *but you can't have more than one client connected to your server at the same time*. In order to do that, you need to use TPL, or worst case, create a thread for each client.

Take a look at [BeginRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread?view=netcore-3.1)/`EndRead` to see what I mean.